# How to filter Flat File Source using script component

Tags: ssis-2012

I have the following scenario:
I have thousands of text files with the below format.The column names are written in separate lines where as the row values are delimited by Pipe(|).

```
START-OF-FILE
PROGRAMNAME=getdata
DATEFORMAT=yyyymmdd

#Some Text
#Some Text
#Some Text
#Some Text
#Some Text
START-OF-FIELDS
Field1
Field2
Field3
------
FieldN
END-OF-FIELDS
TIMESTARTED=Tue May 12 16:04:42 JST 2015
START-OF-DATA
Field1Value|Field2value|Field3Value|...|Field N Value
Field1Value|Field2value|Field3Value|...|Field N Value
------|...........|----|-------
END-OF-DATA
DATARECORDS=30747
TIMEFINISHED=Tue May 12 16:11:53 JST 2015
END-OF-FILE
```

Now I have a corresponding SQL Server table, where I can easily load the data as destination.
Since I am new to SSIS, having trouble as to how to write the Script Component so that I can filter the Source Text files and easily load into sql server table.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do it. If the format of the files are constant, there are some useful properties of the flat file connection manager editor. For example, you can add a new flat file connection into the connection managers. There are some properties such as "Rows to skip" for the above file, you could set this to 18. Then it would start at the columns line with the "|".

Another property of the flat file connection manager that may be useful is that if you open the flat file connection manager, and then click on columns in the side menu, you can set the column delimter to the pipe "|"

But if the format of the file will change, e.g. variable number of header rows, you can use a script task to remove any non-piped rows. e.g. the header and footer.

For example, you can add a method such as file.readalllines and then edit or remove the lines as needed then save the file.

Info about that method is here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

e.g. to remove last line in script task

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines( "input.txt" );
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int count = lines.Length - 1; // all except last line
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    sb.AppendLine(lines[i]);
}
File.WriteAllText("output.txt", sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

USE Below VB Script in your SSIS SCript Component Task as source

```
enter code here

Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Math
Imports System.IO
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper



<Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute()> _
<CLSCompliant(False)> _
Public Class ScriptMain
    Inherits UserComponent
    'Private strSourceDirectory As String
    'Private strSourceFileName As String
    Private strSourceSystem As String
    Private strSourceSubSystem As String
    Private dtBusinessDate As Date


    Public Overrides Sub PreExecute()
        MyBase.PreExecute()
        '
        ' Add your code here for preprocessing or remove if not needed
        ''

    End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub PostExecute()
        MyBase.PostExecute()
        '
        ' Add your code here for postprocessing or remove if not needed
        ' You can set read/write variables here, for example:
        Dim strSourceDirectory As String = Me.Variables.GLOBALSourceDirectory.ToString()
        Dim strSourceFileName As String = Me.Variables.GLOBALSourceFileName.ToString()
        'Dim strSourceSystem As String = Me.Variables.GLOBALSourceSystem.ToString()
        'Dim strSourceSubSystem As String = Me.Variables.GLOBALSourceSubSystem.ToString()
        'Dim dtBusinessDate As Date = Me.Variables.GLOBALBusinessDate.Date


    End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub CreateNewOutputRows()
        '
        ' Add rows by calling the AddRow method on the member variable named "<Output Name>Buffer".
        ' For example, call MyOutputBuffer.AddRow() if your output was named "MyOutput".
        '
        Dim sr As System.IO.StreamReader
        Dim strSourceDirectory As String = Me.Variables.GLOBALSourceDirectory.ToString()
        Dim strSourceFileName As String = Me.Variables.GLOBALSourceFileName.ToString()
        'Dim strSourceSystem As String = Me.Variables.GLOBALSourceSystem.ToString()
        'Dim strSourceSubSystem As String = Me.Variables.GLOBALSourceSubSystem.ToString()
        'Dim dtBusinessDate As Date = Me.Variables.GLOBALBusinessDate.Date

        'sr = New System.IO.StreamReader("C:\QRM_SourceFiles\BBG_BONDS_OUTPUT_YYYYMMDD.txt")
        sr = New System.IO.StreamReader(strSourceDirectory & strSourceFileName)
        Dim lineIndex As Integer = 0
        While (Not sr.EndOfStream)
            Dim line As String = sr.ReadLine()
            If (lineIndex <> 0) Then 'remove header row
                Dim columnArray As String() = line.Split(Convert.ToChar("|"))
                If (columnArray.Length > 1) Then
                    Output0Buffer.AddRow()
                    Output0Buffer.Col0 = columnArray(0).ToString()
                    Output0Buffer.Col3 = columnArray(3).ToString()
                    Output0Buffer.Col4 = columnArray(4).ToString()
                    Output0Buffer.Col5 = columnArray(5).ToString()
                    Output0Buffer.Col6 = columnArray(6).ToString()
                    Output0Buffer.Col7 = columnArray(7).ToString()
                    Output0Buffer.Col8 = columnArray(8).ToString()
                    Output0Buffer.Col9 = columnArray(9).ToString()
                    Output0Buffer.Col10 = columnArray(10).ToString()
                    Output0Buffer.Col11 = columnArray(11).ToString()
                    Output0Buffer.Col12 = columnArray(12).ToString()
                    Output0Buffer.Col13 = columnArray(13).ToString()
                    Output0Buffer.Col14 = columnArray(14).ToString()
                    Output0Buffer.Col15 = columnArray(15).ToString()
                    Output0Buffer.Col16 = columnArray(16).ToString()
                    Output0Buffer.Col17 = columnArray(17).ToString()
                    Output0Buffer.Col18 = columnArray(18).ToString()
                    Output0Buffer.Col19 = columnArray(19).ToString()
                    Output0Buffer.Col20 = columnArray(20).ToString()
                    Output0Buffer.Col21 = columnArray(21).ToString()
                    Output0Buffer.Col22 = columnArray(22).ToString()
                    Output0Buffer.Col23 = columnArray(23).ToString()
                    Output0Buffer.Col24 = columnArray(24).ToString()

                End If
            End If
            lineIndex = lineIndex + 1
        End While
        sr.Close()

    End Sub

End Class
```

Code End